# How to get labels/classes from the predicted images

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification

I have trained a classifier model using cnn and what to classify images, loaded images using flowfromdirectory. After training I tested on unseen data then my prediction values are this:-

```
[[[[0.771866   0.8567589  0.902191  ]
   [0.8756012  0.93743145 0.9572767 ]
   [0.8575856  0.92234766 0.95071596]
   ...
   [0.8285682  0.9203037  0.9460905 ]
   [0.85615414 0.9182381  0.9420978 ]
   [0.7868526  0.8462486  0.8882149 ]]

  [[0.815824   0.8986912  0.93497586]
   [0.88749367 0.94393086 0.96703947]
   [0.8745645  0.93561155 0.9639484 ]
   ...
   [0.85607237 0.93997157 0.96361405]
   [0.8750243  0.937056   0.9653714 ]
   [0.8367853  0.89637643 0.9370449 ]]

  [[0.695155   0.7554943  0.77888066]
   [0.8337961  0.8617642  0.8727031 ]
   [0.8334781  0.84559196 0.86962295]
   ...
   [0.01496893 0.03932272 0.01421419]
   [0.01424129 0.04037565 0.01449471]
   [0.02615304 0.05672317 0.0271827 ]]

  [[0.71646017 0.76629317 0.79345727]
   [0.8340155  0.86742646 0.87385976]
   [0.84214795 0.8550026  0.872459  ]
   ...
   [0.01343644 0.0353599  0.01344425]
   [0.01343626 0.03432167 0.01197887]
   [0.02437622 0.05071671 0.02522665]]
```

How do convert get this as class_indiceis/labels?

Comment: What is the shape of predicted values? What is the shape of your model output? How many images do you feed to predict?

Comment: It looks like you have 9 classes? that's correct?

Comment: @Kaveh predicted shape is  (20, 256, 256)    model output shape is (None, 256, 256, 3). I had feed 1200 images belonging to 3 classes.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel Nope. I have only 3 classes/labels

Comment: You should first make sure that the model output is appropriate, if you have 3 classes, the output should be (None, 3).